# Exporting an Android project while using proguard on adt&sdk 20

Tags: android, obfuscation, adt, proguard

I've updated to the new [adt&sdk 20](http://tools.android.com/download/adt-20-preview), and I'm having problems with the new way Proguard is being used on Eclipse. I'm not a pro with Proguard at all, yet I've always used it and it worked quite easily. I simply edited the "project.properties" file and added there "proguard.config=proguard.cfg", and it worked.

Sadly, some changes were made that I can't find any information of how to work with them. The official website that talks about Proguard (in the Android website) still talks about the older way.

They wrote on the "project.properties" to uncomment the next line:

```
#proguard.config=${sdk.dir}/tools/proguard/proguard-android.txt:proguard-project.txt
```

This didn't work, it gives me these errors when trying to export:

```
Proguard returned with error code 1. See console
java.io.IOException: The output jar is empty. Did you specify the proper '-keep' options?
at proguard.shrink.Shrinker.execute(Shrinker.java:159)
at proguard.ProGuard.shrink(ProGuard.java:275)
at proguard.ProGuard.execute(ProGuard.java:101)
at proguard.ProGuard.main(ProGuard.java:492)
```

Can anyone help me with this? I never had to change the proguard.cfg file before and all was quite automatic. It was very rare that i had to do such a thing.

They also added a file "proguard-project.txt" which probably replaces the proguard.cfg and "extends" from the sdk folder's file, so i wonder: will it be ok to somehow reference to the file in the project instead (and put into the file the content of the "parent" file)? If so, how do I do that?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Ok , the solution is that for some reason , I had the wrong location set for sdk.dir variable on eclipse.

So what I did is to:

> 1. Go to eclipse's preferences
> 2. Searched for variables
> 3. And went to java->build path->classpath variables
> 4. And added "sdk.dir" variable with the value of the directory of
>      android sdk .

Answer (score 3):

If it was working fine before and you haven't learnt Proguard, just change this line:

```
 proguard.config=${sdk.dir}/tools/proguard/proguard-android.txt:proguard-project.txt
```

to this line:

```
 proguard.config=proguard.cfg
```

then you'll have your old Proguard setup back, I'd recommend updating though, it should just work unless your using some 3rd party jars? These are what is it saying is missing and you should use the -keep flag to stop Proguard from removing them when it obfuscates.

Comment: no , their new way of using proguard didn't work even with a totally new android project (hello world) . odd , now on windows it worked fine , and on linux it didn't . i will need to check it out again .

Comment: i've tested it on a fresh linux installation and it worked well , yet on the original linux OS i still get those errors. can you please tell me what's wrong?

Comment: i've also tried your solution , and it says something weird : "invlid proguard configuration file path .../proguard.cfg does not exist or is not a regular file"

Answer (score 1):

create a file proguard.cfg in your project root folder and update your adt to 21 and use proguard v4.8 or 4.9 and dont forget to run Android Lint before exporting APK

Comment: it was a long time ago, and i don't even remember the problem, and i've answered it. however, maybe your answer would help someone else, so thank you.

Answer (score 0):

The path of default config file has been changed to

${sdk.dir}/tools/proguard/proguard-android-optimize.txt

Comment: not an answer to the question (which already got an answer), but good to know, so thanks.

Comment: So how can I tell Proguard about the name change?

Comment: Found it in my project's project.properties.

Answer (score 0):

Using SDK 22, my solution was to copy proguard-project.txt from ${sdk.dir}/tools/proguard/ into my project workspace.

If you look at project.properties, you see that it references `${sdk.dir}/tools/proguard/proguard-android.txt:proguard-project.txt`.

It found ${sdk.dir} just fine, but was looking for proguard-project.txt in the project directory.