# Proguard Android using Action Bar Sherlock

Tags: android, eclipse, actionbarsherlock, proguard

---

**EDIT 4:**
I've tried taking out Action Bar Sherlock and Proguard did it ok. So I guess it is a problem with android-support-v4.jar.

I tried this when including the ABS library, but it didn't work..

```
-keep class android.support.v4.app.** { *; }
-keep interface android.support.v4.app.** { *; }
-keep class com.actionbarsherlock.** { *; }
-keep interface com.actionbarsherlock.** { *; }

-keepattributes *Annotation*
```

Finally, What is weird is that I tried without the **ABS library and without proguard-android.txt** and it worked as well.

**I have no clue of what the problem is.**

---

I've read tons of Q/A about this and tried many solutions but none worked out.

I've tried doing:

```
-injars libs/**
```

And:

```
-libraryjars  libs/**
```

And other things that didn't work..Could you give me your opinion on what I should do?

**I am using 4 external jars:**

- apache-mime4j-0.6.jar
- httpclient-4.2.2.jar
- httpcore-4.2.2.jar
- httpmime-4.2.2.jar

This is error console when I tried to export the signed apk:

```
    [2013-10-15 18:36:12 - ExampleProGuard] Proguard returned with error code 1. See console
[2013-10-15 18:36:12 - ExampleProGuard] Note: there were 364 duplicate class definitions.
[2013-10-15 18:36:12 - ExampleProGuard] Warning: library class android.net.http.AndroidHttpClient extends or implements program class org.apache.http.client.HttpClient
[2013-10-15 18:36:12 - ExampleProGuard] Warning: org.apache.http.client.protocol.RequestAddCookies: can't find referenced class org.apache.commons.logging.LogFactory
[2013-10-15 18:36:12 - ExampleProGuard] Warning: org.apache.http.client.protocol.RequestAddCookies: can't find referenced class org.apache.commons.logging.LogFactory
[2013-10-15 18:36:12 - ExampleProGuard] Warning: org.apache.http.client.protocol.RequestAuthCache: can't find referenced class org.apache.commons.logging.LogFactory
[2013-10-15 18:36:12 - ExampleProGuard] Warning: org.apache.http.client.protocol.RequestAuthCache: can't find referenced class org.apache.commons.logging.LogFactory
[2013-10-15 18:36:12 - ExampleProGuard] Warning: org.apache.http.client.protocol.RequestAuthenticationBase: can't find referenced class org.apache.commons.logging.LogFactory
[2013-10-15 18:36:12 - ExampleProGuard] Warning: org.apache.http.client.protocol.RequestAuthenticationBase: can't find referenced class org.apache.commons.logging.LogFactory
[2013-10-15 18:36:12 - ExampleProGuard] Warning: org.apache.http.client.protocol.RequestClientConnControl: can't find referenced class org.apache.commons.logging.LogFactory
[2013-10-15 18:36:12 - ExampleProGuard] Warning: org.apache.http.client.protocol.RequestClientConnControl: can't find referenced class org.apache.commons.logging.LogFactory
[2013-10-15 18:36:12 - ExampleProGuard] Warning: org.apache.http.client.protocol.ResponseAuthCache: can't find referenced class org.apache.commons.logging.LogFactory
[2013-10-15 18:36:12 - ExampleProGuard] Warning: org.apache.http.client.protocol.ResponseAuthCache: can't find referenced class org.apache.commons.logging.LogFactory
[2013-10-15 18:36:12 - ExampleProGuard] Warning: org.apache.http.client.protocol.ResponseProcessCookies: can't find referenced class org.apache.commons.logging.LogFactory
[2013-10-15 18:36:12 - ExampleProGuard] Warning: org.apache.http.client.protocol.ResponseProcessCookies: can't find referenced class org.apache.commons.logging.LogFactory
[2013-10-15 18:36:12 - ExampleProGuard] Warning: org.apache.http.impl.auth.BasicScheme: can't find referenced class org.apache.commons.codec.binary.Base64
[2013-10-15 18:36:12 - ExampleProGuard] Warning: org.apache.http.impl.auth.BasicScheme: can't find referenced class org.apache.commons.codec.binary.Base64
[2013-10-15 18:36:12 - ExampleProGuard] Warning: org.apache.http.impl.auth.GGSSchemeBase: can't find referenced class org.apache.commons.logging.LogFactory
[2013-10-15 18:36:12 - ExampleProGuard] Warning: org.apache.http.impl.auth.GGSSchemeBase: can't find referenced class org.apache.commons.codec.binary.Base64
[2013-10-15 18:36:12 - ExampleProGuard] Warning: org.apache.http.impl.auth.GGSSchemeBase: can't find referenced class org.apache.commons.codec.binary.Base64
[2013-10-15 18:36:12 - ExampleProGuard] Warning: org.apache.http.impl.auth.GGSSchemeBase: can't find referenced class org.ietf.jgss.GSSManager
[2013-10-15 18:36:12 - ExampleProGuard] Warning: org.apache.http.impl.auth.GGSSchemeBase: can't find referenced class org.ietf.jgss.GSSName
[2013-10-15 18:36:12 - ExampleProGuard] Warning: org.apache.http.impl.auth.GGSSchemeBase: can't find referenced class org.ietf.jgss.GSSManager
[2013-10-15 18:36:12 - ExampleProGuard] Warning: org.apache.http.impl.auth.GGSSchemeBase: can't find referenced class org.ietf.jgss.GSSName
[2013-10-15 18:36:12 - ExampleProGuard] Warning: org.apache.http.impl.auth.GGSSchemeBase: can't find referenced class org.ietf.jgss.GSSManager
[2013-10-15 18:36:12 - ExampleProGuard] Warning: org.apache.http.impl.auth.GGSSchemeBase: can't find referenced class org.ietf.jgss.GSSContext
[2013-10-15 18:36:12 - ExampleProGuard] Warning: org.apache.http.impl.auth.GGSSchemeBase: can't find referenced class org.ietf.jgss.GSSContext
[2013-10-15 18:36:12 - ExampleProGuard] Warning: org.apache.http.impl.auth.GGSSchemeBase: can't find referenced class org.ietf.jgss.GSSContext
[2013-10-15 18:36:12 - ExampleProGuard] Warning: org.apache.http.impl.auth.GGSSchemeBase: can't find referenced class org.ietf.jgss.GSSException
[2013-10-15 18:36:12 - ExampleProGuard] Warning: org.apache.http.impl.auth.GGSSchemeBase: can't find referenced class org.ietf.jgss.GSSException
[2013-10-15 18:36:12 - ExampleProGuard] Warning: org.apache.http.impl.auth.GGSSchemeBase: can't find referenced class org.ietf.jgss.GSSException
[2013-10-15 18:36:12 - ExampleProGuard] Warning: org.apache.http.impl.auth.GGSSchemeBase: can't find referenced class org.apache.commons.codec.binary.Base64
[2013-10-15 18:36:12 - ExampleProGuard] Warning: org.apache.http.impl.auth.GGSSchemeBase: can't find referenced class org.apache.commons.codec.binary.Base64
[2013-10-15 18:36:12 - ExampleProGuard] Warning: org.apache.http.impl.auth.GGSSchemeBase: can't find referenced class org.apache.commons.logging.LogFactory
[2013-10-15 18:36:12 - ExampleProGuard] Warning: org.apache.http.impl.auth.GGSSchemeBase: can't find referenced class org.ietf.jgss.GSSManager
[2013-10-15 18:36:12 - ExampleProGuard] Warning: org.apache.http.impl.auth.GGSSchemeBase: can't find referenced class org.ietf.jgss.GSSName
[2013-10-15 18:36:12 - ExampleProGuard] Warning: org.apache.http.impl.auth.GGSSchemeBase: can't find referenced class org.ietf.jgss.GSSContext
[2013-10-15 18:36:12 - ExampleProGuard] Warning: org.apache.http.impl.auth.GGSSchemeBase: can't find referenced class org.apache.commons.codec.binary.Base64
[2013-10-15 18:36:12 - ExampleProGuard] Warning: org.apache.http.impl.auth.GGSSchemeBase: can't find referenced class org.ietf.jgss.GSSManager
[2013-10-15 18:36:12 - ExampleProGuard] Warning: org.apache.http.impl.auth.GGSSchemeBase: can't find referenced class org.ietf.jgss.Oid
[2013-10-15 18:36:12 - ExampleProGuard] Warning: org.apache.http.impl.auth.GGSSchemeBase: can't find referenced class org.ietf.jgss.Oid
[2013-10-15 18:36:12 - ExampleProGuard] Warning: org.apache.http.impl.auth.GGSSchemeBase: can't find referenced class org.ietf.jgss.GSSManager
[2013-10-15 18:36:12 - ExampleProGuard] Warning: org.apache.http.impl.auth.GGSSchemeBase: can't find referenced class org.ietf.jgss.GSSName
[2013-10-15 18:36:12 - ExampleProGuard] Warning: org.apache.http.impl.auth.GGSSchemeBase: can't find referenced class org.ietf.jgss.GSSContext
[2013-10-15 18:36:12 - ExampleProGuard] Warning: org.apache.http.impl.auth.GGSSchemeBase: can't find referenced class org.ietf.jgss.GSSException
[2013-10-15 18:36:12 - ExampleProGuard] Warning: org.apache.http.impl.auth.KerberosScheme: can't find referenced class org.ietf.jgss.Oid
[2013-10-15 18:36:12 - ExampleProGuard] Warning: org.apache.http.impl.auth.KerberosScheme: can't find referenced class org.ietf.jgss.Oid
[2013-10-15 18:36:12 - ExampleProGuard] Warning: org.apache.http.impl.auth.KerberosScheme: can't find referenced class org.ietf.jgss.GSSException
[2013-10-15 18:36:12 - ExampleProGuard] Warning: org.apache.http.impl.auth.NTLMEngineImpl$NTLMMessage: can't find referenced class org.apache.commons.codec.binary.Base64
[2013-10-15 18:36:12 - ExampleProGuard] Warning: org.apache.http.impl.auth.NTLMEngineImpl$NTLMMessage: can't find referenced class org.apache.commons.codec.binary.Base64
[2013-10-15 18:36:12 - ExampleProGuard] Warning: org.apache.http.impl.auth.NTLMEngineImpl$NTLMMessage: can't find referenced class org.apache.commons.codec.binary.Base64
[2013-10-15 18:36:12 - ExampleProGuard] Warning: org.apache.http.impl.auth.NegotiateScheme: can't find referenced class org.apache.commons.logging.LogFactory
[2013-10-15 18:36:12 - ExampleProGuard] Warning: org.apache.http.impl.auth.NegotiateScheme: can't find referenced class org.ietf.jgss.Oid
[2013-10-15 18:36:12 - ExampleProGuard] Warning: org.apache.http.impl.auth.NegotiateScheme: can't find referenced class org.ietf.jgss.Oid
[2013-10-15 18:36:12 - ExampleProGuard] Warning: org.apache.http.impl.auth.NegotiateScheme: can't find referenced class org.ietf.jgss.GSSException
[2013-10-15 18:36:12 - ExampleProGuard] Warning: org.apache.http.impl.auth.NegotiateScheme: can't find referenced class org.ietf.jgss.GSSException
[2013-10-15 18:36:12 - ExampleProGuard] Warning: org.apache.http.impl.auth.NegotiateScheme: can't find referenced class org.apache.commons.logging.LogFactory
[2013-10-15 18:36:12 - ExampleProGuard] Warning: org.apache.http.impl.auth.NegotiateScheme: can't find referenced class org.ietf.jgss.GSSException
[2013-10-15 18:36:12 - ExampleProGuard] Warning: org.apache.http.impl.auth.NegotiateScheme: can't find referenced class org.ietf.jgss.Oid
[2013-10-15 18:36:12 - ExampleProGuard] Warning: org.apache.http.impl.auth.SPNegoScheme: can't find referenced class org.ietf.jgss.Oid
[2013-10-15 18:36:12 - ExampleProGuard] Warning: org.apache.http.impl.auth.SPNegoScheme: can't find referenced class org.ietf.jgss.Oid
[2013-10-15 18:36:12 - ExampleProGuard] Warning: org.apache.http.impl.auth.SPNegoScheme: can't find referenced class org.ietf.jgss.GSSException
[2013-10-15 18:36:12 - ExampleProGuard] Warning: org.apache.http.impl.client.AbstractAuthenticationHandler: can't find referenced class org.apache.commons.logging.LogFactory
[2013-10-15 18:36:12 - ExampleProGuard] Warning: org.apache.http.impl.client.AbstractAuthenticationHandler: can't find referenced class org.apache.commons.logging.LogFactory
[2013-10-15 18:36:12 - ExampleProGuard] Warning: org.apache.http.impl.client.AbstractHttpClient: can't find referenced class org.apache.commons.logging.LogFactory
[2013-10-15 18:36:12 - ExampleProGuard] Warning: org.apache.http.impl.client.AbstractHttpClient: can't find referenced class org.apache.commons.logging.LogFactory
[2013-10-15 18:36:12 - ExampleProGuard] Warning: org.apache.http.impl.client.AuthenticationStrategyAdaptor: can't find referenced class org.apache.commons.logging.LogFactory
[2013-10-15 18:36:12 - ExampleProGuard] Warning: org.apache.http.impl.client.AuthenticationStrategyAdaptor: can't find referenced class org.apache.commons.logging.LogFactory
[2013-10-15 18:36:12 - ExampleProGuard] Warning: org.apache.http.impl.client.AuthenticationStrategyImpl: can't find referenced class org.apache.commons.logging.LogFactory
[2013-10-15 18:36:12 - ExampleProGuard] Warning: org.apache.http.impl.client.AuthenticationStrategyImpl: can't find referenced class org.apache.commons.logging.LogFactory
[2013-10-15 18:36:12 - ExampleProGuard] Warning: org.apache.http.impl.client.AutoRetryHttpClient: can't find referenced class org.apache.commons.logging.LogFactory
[2013-10-15 18:36:12 - ExampleProGuard] Warning: org.apache.http.impl.client.AutoRetryHttpClient: can't find referenced class org.apache.commons.logging.LogFactory
[2013-10-15 18:36:12 - ExampleProGuard] Warning: org.apache.http.impl.client.DefaultRedirectHandler: can't find referenced class org.apache.commons.logging.LogFactory
[2013-10-15 18:36:12 - ExampleProGuard] Warning: org.apache.http.impl.client.DefaultRedirectHandler: can't find referenced class org.apache.commons.logging.LogFactory
[2013-10-15 18:36:12 - ExampleProGuard] Warning: org.apache.http.impl.client.DefaultRedirectStrategy: can't find referenced class org.apache.commons.logging.LogFactory
[2013-10-15 18:36:12 - ExampleProGuard] Warning: org.apache.http.impl.client.DefaultRedirectStrategy: can't find referenced class org.apache.commons.logging.LogFactory
[2013-10-15 18:36:12 - ExampleProGuard] Warning: org.apache.http.impl.client.DefaultRequestDirector: can't find referenced class org.apache.commons.logging.LogFactory
[2013-10-15 18:36:12 - ExampleProGuard] Warning: org.apache.http.impl.client.DefaultRequestDirector: can't find referenced class org.apache.commons.logging.LogFactory
[2013-10-15 18:36:12 - ExampleProGuard] Warning: org.apache.http.impl.client.HttpAuthenticator: can't find referenced class org.apache.commons.logging.LogFactory
[2013-10-15 18:36:12 - ExampleProGuard] Warning: org.apache.http.impl.client.HttpAuthenticator: can't find referenced class org.apache.commons.logging.LogFactory
[2013-10-15 18:36:12 - ExampleProGuard] Warning: org.apache.http.impl.conn.BasicClientConnectionManager: can't find referenced class org.apache.commons.logging.LogFactory
[2013-10-15 18:36:12 - ExampleProGuard] Warning: org.apache.http.impl.conn.BasicClientConnectionManager: can't find referenced class org.apache.commons.logging.LogFactory
[2013-10-15 18:36:12 - ExampleProGuard] Warning: org.apache.http.impl.conn.DefaultClientConnection: can't find referenced class org.apache.commons.logging.LogFactory
[2013-10-15 18:36:12 - ExampleProGuard] Warning: org.apache.http.impl.conn.DefaultClientConnection: can't find referenced class org.apache.commons.logging.LogFactory
[2013-10-15 18:36:12 - ExampleProGuard] Warning: org.apache.http.impl.conn.DefaultClientConnection: can't find referenced class org.apache.commons.logging.LogFactory
[2013-10-15 18:36:12 - ExampleProGuard] Warning: org.apache.http.impl.conn.DefaultClientConnectionOperator: can't find referenced class org.apache.commons.logging.LogFactory
[2013-10-15 18:36:12 - ExampleProGuard] Warning: org.apache.http.impl.conn.DefaultClientConnectionOperator: can't find referenced class org.apache.commons.logging.LogFactory
[2013-10-15 18:36:12 - ExampleProGuard] Warning: org.apache.http.impl.conn.DefaultHttpResponseParser: can't find referenced class org.apache.commons.logging.LogFactory
[2013-10-15 18:36:12 - ExampleProGuard] Warning: org.apache.http.impl.conn.DefaultHttpResponseParser: can't find referenced class org.apache.commons.logging.LogFactory
[2013-10-15 18:36:12 - ExampleProGuard] Warning: org.apache.http.impl.conn.DefaultResponseParser: can't find referenced class org.apache.commons.logging.LogFactory
[2013-10-15 18:36:12 - ExampleProGuard] Warning: org.apache.http.impl.conn.DefaultResponseParser: can't find referenced class org.apache.commons.logging.LogFactory
[2013-10-15 18:36:12 - ExampleProGuard] Warning: org.apache.http.impl.conn.IdleConnectionHandler: can't find referenced class org.apache.commons.logging.LogFactory
[2013-10-15 18:36:12 - ExampleProGuard] Warning: org.apache.http.impl.conn.IdleConnectionHandler: can't find referenced class org.apache.commons.logging.LogFactory
[2013-10-15 18:36:12 - ExampleProGuard] Warning: org.apache.http.impl.conn.InMemoryDnsResolver: can't find referenced class org.apache.commons.logging.LogFactory
[2013-10-15 18:36:12 - ExampleProGuard] Warning: org.apache.http.impl.conn.InMemoryDnsResolver: can't find referenced class org.apache.commons.logging.LogFactory
[2013-10-15 18:36:12 - ExampleProGuard] Warning: org.apache.http.impl.conn.PoolingClientConnectionManager: can't find referenced class org.apache.commons.logging.LogFactory
[2013-10-15 18:36:12 - ExampleProGuard] Warning: org.apache.http.impl.conn.PoolingClientConnectionManager: can't find referenced class org.apache.commons.logging.LogFactory
[2013-10-15 18:36:12 - ExampleProGuard] Warning: org.apache.http.impl.conn.SingleClientConnManager: can't find referenced class org.apache.commons.logging.LogFactory
[2013-10-15 18:36:12 - ExampleProGuard] Warning: org.apache.http.impl.conn.SingleClientConnManager: can't find referenced class org.apache.commons.logging.LogFactory
[2013-10-15 18:36:12 - ExampleProGuard] Warning: org.apache.http.impl.conn.tsccm.AbstractConnPool: can't find referenced class org.apache.commons.logging.LogFactory
[2013-10-15 18:36:12 - ExampleProGuard] Warning: org.apache.http.impl.conn.tsccm.AbstractConnPool: can't find referenced class org.apache.commons.logging.LogFactory
[2013-10-15 18:36:12 - ExampleProGuard] Warning: org.apache.http.impl.conn.tsccm.ConnPoolByRoute: can't find referenced class org.apache.commons.logging.LogFactory
[2013-10-15 18:36:12 - ExampleProGuard] Warning: org.apache.http.impl.conn.tsccm.ConnPoolByRoute: can't find referenced class org.apache.commons.logging.LogFactory
[2013-10-15 18:36:12 - ExampleProGuard] Warning: org.apache.http.impl.conn.tsccm.RouteSpecificPool: can't find referenced class org.apache.commons.logging.LogFactory
[2013-10-15 18:36:12 - ExampleProGuard] Warning: org.apache.http.impl.conn.tsccm.RouteSpecificPool: can't find referenced class org.apache.commons.logging.LogFactory
[2013-10-15 18:36:12 - ExampleProGuard] Warning: org.apache.http.impl.conn.tsccm.ThreadSafeClientConnManager: can't find referenced class org.apache.commons.logging.LogFactory
[2013-10-15 18:36:12 - ExampleProGuard] Warning: org.apache.http.impl.conn.tsccm.ThreadSafeClientConnManager: can't find referenced class org.apache.commons.logging.LogFactory
[2013-10-15 18:36:12 - ExampleProGuard] Warning: org.apache.james.mime4j.codec.Base64InputStream: can't find referenced class org.apache.commons.logging.LogFactory
[2013-10-15 18:36:12 - ExampleProGuard] Warning: org.apache.james.mime4j.codec.Base64InputStream: can't find referenced class org.apache.commons.logging.LogFactory
[2013-10-15 18:36:12 - ExampleProGuard] Warning: org.apache.james.mime4j.codec.DecoderUtil: can't find referenced class org.apache.commons.logging.LogFactory
[2013-10-15 18:36:12 - ExampleProGuard] Warning: org.apache.james.mime4j.codec.DecoderUtil: can't find referenced class org.apache.commons.logging.LogFactory
[2013-10-15 18:36:12 - ExampleProGuard] Warning: org.apache.james.mime4j.codec.QuotedPrintableInputStream: can't find referenced class org.apache.commons.logging.LogFactory
[2013-10-15 18:36:12 - ExampleProGuard] Warning: org.apache.james.mime4j.codec.QuotedPrintableInputStream: can't find referenced class org.apache.commons.logging.LogFactory
[2013-10-15 18:36:12 - ExampleProGuard] Warning: org.apache.james.mime4j.descriptor.DefaultBodyDescriptor: can't find referenced class org.apache.commons.logging.LogFactory
[2013-10-15 18:36:12 - ExampleProGuard] Warning: org.apache.james.mime4j.descriptor.DefaultBodyDescriptor: can't find referenced class org.apache.commons.logging.LogFactory
[2013-10-15 18:36:12 - ExampleProGuard] Warning: org.apache.james.mime4j.field.AddressListField: can't find referenced class org.apache.commons.logging.LogFactory
[2013-10-15 18:36:12 - ExampleProGuard] Warning: org.apache.james.mime4j.field.AddressListField: can't find referenced class org.apache.commons.logging.LogFactory
[2013-10-15 18:36:12 - ExampleProGuard] Warning: org.apache.james.mime4j.field.ContentDispositionField: can't find referenced class org.apache.commons.logging.LogFactory
[2013-10-15 18:36:12 - ExampleProGuard] Warning: org.apache.james.mime4j.field.ContentDispositionField: can't find referenced class org.apache.commons.logging.LogFactory
[2013-10-15 18:36:12 - ExampleProGuard] Warning: org.apache.james.mime4j.field.ContentTypeField: can't find referenced class org.apache.commons.logging.LogFactory
[2013-10-15 18:36:12 - ExampleProGuard] Warning: org.apache.james.mime4j.field.ContentTypeField: can't find referenced class org.apache.commons.logging.LogFactory
[2013-10-15 18:36:12 - ExampleProGuard] Warning: org.apache.james.mime4j.field.DateTimeField: can't find referenced class org.apache.commons.logging.LogFactory
[2013-10-15 18:36:12 - ExampleProGuard] Warning: org.apache.james.mime4j.field.DateTimeField: can't find referenced class org.apache.commons.logging.LogFactory
[2013-10-15 18:36:12 - ExampleProGuard] Warning: org.apache.james.mime4j.field.MailboxField: can't find referenced class org.apache.commons.logging.LogFactory
[2013-10-15 18:36:12 - ExampleProGuard] Warning: org.apache.james.mime4j.field.MailboxField: can't find referenced class org.apache.commons.logging.LogFactory
[2013-10-15 18:36:12 - ExampleProGuard] Warning: org.apache.james.mime4j.field.MailboxListField: can't find referenced class org.apache.commons.logging.LogFactory
[2013-10-15 18:36:12 - ExampleProGuard] Warning: org.apache.james.mime4j.field.MailboxListField: can't find referenced class org.apache.commons.logging.LogFactory
[2013-10-15 18:36:12 - ExampleProGuard] Warning: org.apache.james.mime4j.message.BodyFactory: can't find referenced class org.apache.commons.logging.LogFactory
[2013-10-15 18:36:12 - ExampleProGuard] Warning: org.apache.james.mime4j.message.BodyFactory: can't find referenced class org.apache.commons.logging.LogFactory
[2013-10-15 18:36:12 - ExampleProGuard] Warning: org.apache.james.mime4j.parser.AbstractEntity: can't find referenced class org.apache.commons.logging.LogFactory
[2013-10-15 18:36:12 - ExampleProGuard] Warning: org.apache.james.mime4j.parser.AbstractEntity: can't find referenced class org.apache.commons.logging.LogFactory
[2013-10-15 18:36:12 - ExampleProGuard] Warning: org.apache.james.mime4j.storage.DefaultStorageProvider: can't find referenced class org.apache.commons.logging.LogFactory
[2013-10-15 18:36:12 - ExampleProGuard] Warning: org.apache.james.mime4j.storage.DefaultStorageProvider: can't find referenced class org.apache.commons.logging.LogFactory
[2013-10-15 18:36:12 - ExampleProGuard] Warning: org.apache.james.mime4j.util.CharsetUtil: can't find referenced class org.apache.commons.logging.LogFactory
[2013-10-15 18:36:12 - ExampleProGuard] Warning: org.apache.james.mime4j.util.CharsetUtil: can't find referenced class org.apache.commons.logging.LogFactory
[2013-10-15 18:36:12 - ExampleProGuard] Warning: org.apache.james.mime4j.util.MimeUtil: can't find referenced class org.apache.commons.logging.LogFactory
[2013-10-15 18:36:12 - ExampleProGuard] Warning: org.apache.james.mime4j.util.MimeUtil: can't find referenced class org.apache.commons.logging.LogFactory
[2013-10-15 18:36:12 - ExampleProGuard]       You should check if you need to specify additional program jars.
[2013-10-15 18:36:12 - ExampleProGuard] Warning: there were 134 unresolved references to classes or interfaces.
[2013-10-15 18:36:12 - ExampleProGuard]          You may need to specify additional library jars (using '-libraryjars').
[2013-10-15 18:36:12 - ExampleProGuard] Warning: there were 1 instances of library classes depending on program classes.
[2013-10-15 18:36:12 - ExampleProGuard]          You must avoid such dependencies, since the program classes will
[2013-10-15 18:36:12 - ExampleProGuard]          be processed, while the library classes will remain unchanged.
[2013-10-15 18:36:12 - ExampleProGuard] java.io.IOException: Please correct the above warnings first.
[2013-10-15 18:36:12 - ExampleProGuard]     at proguard.Initializer.execute(Initializer.java:321)
[2013-10-15 18:36:12 - ExampleProGuard]     at proguard.ProGuard.initialize(ProGuard.java:211)
[2013-10-15 18:36:12 - ExampleProGuard]     at proguard.ProGuard.execute(ProGuard.java:86)
[2013-10-15 18:36:12 - ExampleProGuard]     at proguard.ProGuard.main(ProGuard.java:492)
```

---

**EDIT**

First, thank you Eric for your answer.

I tried:

```
 -dotwarn org.apache.common.**
```

and

```
 -dontwarn org.**
```

But it shows the exact same console errors.

I saw this [thread](https://stackoverflow.com/a/10967049/1598935) so I tried adding a new classpath variable with the path to sdk but it shows the same console errors.

**This is my project.properties file where it refers too to the Action Bar Sherlock**

```
    # This file is automatically generated by Android Tools.
# Do not modify this file -- YOUR CHANGES WILL BE ERASED!
#
# This file must be checked in Version Control Systems.
#
# To customize properties used by the Ant build system edit
# "ant.properties", and override values to adapt the script to your
# project structure.
#
# To enable ProGuard to shrink and obfuscate your code, uncomment this (available properties: sdk.dir, user.home):
proguard.config=${sdk.dir}/tools/proguard/proguard-android.txt:proguard-project.txt

# Project target.
target=android-15
android.library=false
android.library.reference.1=../JakeWharton-ActionBarSherlock-5b15c92/actionbarsherlock
```

**EDIT 2:**

As it says on Action Sherlock Bar [website](http://actionbarsherlock.com/faq.html) I tried this too without changing at all the error console:

```
-keep class android.support.v4.app.** { *; }
-keep interface android.support.v4.app.** { *; }
-keep class com.actionbarsherlock.** { *; }
-keep interface com.actionbarsherlock.** { *; }

-keepattributes *Annotation*
```

**EDIT 3:**

I tried taking off the external jars (not ABS which is a library) from the project but it still shows the exact same error. I dont get where it is coming from.

Comment: [Here][1] is what solved the similar porblem!


  [1]: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/19414823/export-signed-android-apk-with-proguard

Comment: @eyyo Buddy, did you got the solutions for this issue ? If so, could you share with me so that it may help me solve the similar issue that I am facing ? Regards.

Comment: @HareshChaudhary I couldn't solve it.. And actually I am not working with Android at the moment. If you find a solution please answer the question so we can give it a happy end. :D Good luck!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I have answered this before [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/32798394/classes-jar-not-found-after-using-proguard-inn-android-studio/32927577#32927577), I am putting it here too so that it may help someone.

I had the same issue and read somewhere a workaround to this issue and it was to disable minifyEnabled, generate signed APK.

```
buildTypes {
    release {
        minifyEnabled false
        shrinkResources true
        proguardFiles 'proguard-project.txt'
    }
```

I never face this issue before updating buildTool to 23.0.

Also, with this newer version, you need to add this to your Progaurd.txt file.

```
-keep public class com.google.android.gms.* { public *; }
-dontwarn com.google.android.gms.**
```

Hope this helps to resolve your issue too.

Answer (score 8):

Some classes like `org.apache.commons.logging.LogFactory` are missing from your libraries. Apparently, your application doesn't use them anyway, so you can tell ProGuard it's okay. For instance:

```
-dontwarn org.apache.commons.**
```

See the ProGuard manual > Troubleshooting > [Warning: can't find referenced class](http://proguard.sourceforge.net/manual/troubleshooting.html#unresolvedclass).

Other classes like `org.apache.http.**` are already present in the Android runtime. You shouldn't duplicate them in your application libraries, since the versions in the Android runtime get precedence anyway.

See the ProGuard manual > Troubleshooting > [Warning: library class ... depends on program class ...](http://proguard.sourceforge.net/manual/troubleshooting.html#dependency)

Finally, you shouldn't specify `-injars` or `-libraryjars` options in your configuration file. The Ant/Eclipse/Gradle build process already automatically specifies all the necessary `-injars`, `-outjars`, and `-libraryjars` for you, based on the contents of your project.

See the ProGuard manual > Troubleshooting > [Note: duplicate definition of program/library class](http://proguard.sourceforge.net/manual/troubleshooting.html#duplicateclass)

Comment: thank you for your answer I tried this but it didn't work as it shows the same console error. I added my project.properties to the question. Regards

Comment: Mr Lafortune, thank you for your time. I know you are on charge of Proguard project so it is for me quit an honor to be talking directly to you. I tried your solution but it doesn't help, actually nothing I did changes the console errors. The same project without ActionBarSherlock exports fine using Proguard. I tried many things (My question shows them) but nothing works. Can you give me a clue or something I could try? Thank you very much.