# Error when minifying Android app with R8 after upgrading Android Gradle Plugin to 8.0.2

Tags: build, proguard, minify, android-build, android-r8

I recently upgraded the Android Gradle Plugin in my Android app project from version 7.4.2 to 8.0.2. However, I'm now encountering an error during the release build when the minifyReleaseWithR8 task is executed.

The error message I'm getting is as follows:

```bash
Task :app:minifyReleaseWithR8
AGPBI: {"kind":"error","text":"Library class android.test.AndroidTestRunner extends program class junit.runner.BaseTestRunner","sources":[{}],"tool":"R8"}
Library class android.test.AndroidTestRunner extends program class junit.runner.BaseTestRunner

AGPBI: {"kind":"error","text":"Library class android.test.InstrumentationTestCase extends program class junit.framework.TestCase","sources":[{}],"tool":"R8"}
Library class android.test.InstrumentationTestCase extends program class junit.framework.TestCase

Task :app:minifyReleaseWithR8 FAILED
```

The error seems to be related to missing service classes and conflicts between library classes and program classes.

These errors only started occurring after I updated the Android Gradle Plugin. I've tried cleaning the project and ensuring that all dependencies are up to date, but the issue persists.

Has anyone else encountered a similar issue when upgrading to Android Gradle Plugin 8.0.2? How can I resolve these errors and successfully minify my release build with R8?

Any help or suggestions would be greatly appreciated. Thank you!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

We fixed the problem by adding

```
-dontwarn com.squareup.okhttp.CipherSuite
-dontwarn com.squareup.okhttp.ConnectionSpec
-dontwarn com.squareup.okhttp.TlsVersion
```

to the `app/proguard-rules.pro`.

It seems like some minification warnings were treated as errors.

Comment: Can you help me? Please)))
I got next message:
```AGPBI: {"kind":"error","text":"Library class android.net.http.AndroidHttpClient implements program class org.apache.http.client.HttpClient","sources":[{}],"tool":"R8"}```

Comment: Did you try this? https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20144244/warning-library-class-android-net-http-androidhttpclient-extends-or-implements

Comment: How did you find that these were the sources of the issue?