# ADT v23 + SDK 23 - Android "L" - missing Proguard?

Tags: android, adt, proguard, android-5.0-lollipop

Recently I've updated to the newest Android "L" SDK versions (and the ADT plugin of course).

I've updated my app and wanted to export it, and then got this old, known message :

> invalid proguard configuration file path

I remembered I had a similar problem before, and went back to it [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/10967049/878126). Indeed, I had the missing variable for some reason.

However, I still got the same error. Then I went to the ".../tools" folder of the sdk , and didn't find any proguard file/folder.

I've tried to re-install everything related to the SDK, but I still can't find it.

Has google accidentally removed it? or maybe does it use something else?

What is going on?

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/a/24456942/115145

Answer (score 1, accepted):

OK, I think this got solved, by updating to a new version of ADT&SDK : 23.0.2